# Is there a function with a better time complexity than list.insert()?

Tags: python

I know that there are ways to speed things up using a numpy array or numba, but I hope there is a better way of doing things just using the libraries that came with python (without using pip).
It could be a different data structure, but it must sorted (i.e. not hash tables)
I have already tried collections.deque (linked lists), though it seems that I am better off using list.

(cProfile time analysis)

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   163232    0.915    0.000    0.915    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'collections.deque' objects}
   163232    0.654    0.000    0.654    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
```

Comment: Is your list ordered?

Comment: I used the list that you create by doing list = []

Comment: I understand, but are the values that are inside the list ordered? In that case you could use bisect for fast insertion.

Comment: Otherwise you can use blist, although you would have to install a module for that

Comment: bisect.insort seems to have to time complexity of O(n) though, similar to the list.insert

Comment: Also, the I know the index that I want to insert it at, so the problem is not finding where to insert it - O(log(n)), but the actual insertion part - O(n)